# Postman Test Need to Get Random With Title Contains

Tags: javascript, postman

I have this test that I would like to modify and I just don't know how to do it. For this test, I am getting a random item from the response array and setting the CategoryID collection variable. The problem is that I use the CategoryID for my PUT requests and may be altering items that should not be altered. I would like to get the CategoryID from a random item where the title contains "Test" if that is possible, I just don't know how to do it and would appreciate the help. My only experience with Postman has been with a Udemy course so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the test I need altered:

```
pm.test('Ensure item is there', () => {
pm.expect(response).to.be.an('array');
pm.expect(response.length).to.be.above(0);

const index = Math.trunc(Math.random() * response.length);
const item = response[index];
pm.expect(item).to.be.an('object');
pm.expect(item).to.haveOwnProperty('id');
pm.collectionVariables.set('CategoryID', item.id);
});
```

Here is an example of the response:

```
[
{
    "title": "Testprimary",
    "color": "salmon",
    "id": "273bda70-2dbc-429f-b143-045dccbffea7",
    "lastModified": "2024-03-06T22:12:43.161"
},
{
    "title": "Relationships",
    "color": "FF63C7",
    "id": "b46c40c2-37e1-46d7-a8e1-0ea235f071ec",
    "lastModified": "2024-01-25T22:18:22.6177142"
}]
```

Here is the test again with what I have come up with. In the if block I would like to grab another item from the array, how would I do that without duplicating the code I have already?

```
pm.test('Ensure item is there', () => {
pm.expect(response).to.be.an('array');
pm.expect(response.length).to.be.above(0);

const index = Math.trunc(Math.random() * response.length);
const item = response[index];
pm.expect(item).to.be.an('object');
pm.expect(item).to.haveOwnProperty('id');
if (!item.title.includes('TEST')) {
    console.log(item.id);
    console.log(item.title);
    
} 
else {
    pm.collectionVariables.set('CategoryID', item.id);
} 

});
```

Comment: How about providing an example response?  Postman uses JavaScript under the hood, so this is more of a JavaScript question.     Postman also has the Lodash library available in the  Sandbox, so you can utilise the map() and random() methods.  I would maybe recommend a visit to the Postman Learning Centre if your only experience has been Udemy.  Start with the basics.

Comment: I have provided a sample of the response and my attempt at getting this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this without grabbing a random number or anything like that.

```
pm.test('Ensure item is there', () => {
   pm.expect(response).to.be.an('array');
   pm.expect(response.length).to.be.above(0);

   var element = response.filter(function(item) { return item.title.includes ('TEST'); });
   if (element.length > 0) {
       const index = Math.trunc(Math.random() * element.length);
       const item = element[index];
       pm.collectionVariables.set('CategoryID', item.id);
   } 
});
```

This is working much better. Basically, I filter the array to get all of the elements with TEST in their name and then use the if block to get a random item from the array of items with TEST in their name and then set the CategoryID.

Comment: That doesn't answer your own question.  That will just return the first Title that contains "Test" from the filter array.  It will be the same title each time.  Your original post said you wanted a random title.

Comment: I changed it so it is getting a random item with TEST in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```js
pm.test("title contains Test", function () {
    array.forEach((x) => {
        if(x.title.includes("Test")){
            pm.collectionVariables.set('categorieId', x.id)
        } else {
            console.log('does not contain')
        }
    })
})
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This should return a random (sample) ID from your filter array.

Based on the following response.

```js
[
    {
        "title": "Test One",
        "color": "Blue",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "title": "Relationships",
        "color": "Pink",
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "title": "Test Two",
        "color": "Orange",
        "id": "3"
    }
]
```

I've wrapped everything in a PM test block.  As soon as the first pm.expect assertion fails, it will stop executing any more code within that block.

Therefore I have a few assertions checking that the initial array exists, the filtered array exists, and the random test title ID also exists before I set the collection variable.

```js
const response = pm.response.json();

pm.test('Set random test title ID', () => {
    pm.expect(response, "response is not an array").to.be.an('array').that.is.not.empty;
    let testTitles = response.filter(obj => obj.title.includes('Test'));
    pm.expect(testTitles, "no test titles").to.be.an('array').that.is.not.empty;
    let randomTestTitleId = (_.sample(testTitles)).id
    pm.expect(randomTestTitleId).to.not.be.undefined;
    console.log(`Random test ID: ${randomTestTitleId}`)
    pm.collectionVariables.set("CategoryID", randomTestTitleId);
});
```

I had to run it a few times against Postman Echo as two objects isn't a very large sample pool.

[image]

I've tested with an example response with only one object with test in the title (which still passes) and without any objects with test, which quite rightly fails.  As there is two tests for arrays, I've added custom assertion text.